# Q: Regex Challenge REAL tag-striper

Tags: regex, xml, html, xhtml

Q: Regex Challenge REAL tag-striper
[en] With one (or two) regex get the result: TEXTO1|TEXTO2|TEXTO3 e TEXTO4|TEXTO5|TEXTO6[/en]
[pt] Com uma (ou duas) regex obter como resultado: TEXTO1|TEXTO2|TEXTO3 e TEXTO4|TEXTO5|TEXTO6[/pt]
[en] From the string below between INICIO and FIM[/en]:
[pt] Da string abaixo entre INICIO e FIM[pt] 
INICIO<aaa>TEXTO1</aaa><bbb></bbb>
<?xml:proriety>TEXTO2</xml:proriety="atribute">
<aaa>TEXTO3 e TEXTO4</aaa>
entre-tags-não-importam
<bbb>TEXTO5
</bbb>
<bbb>
TEXTO6
</bbb>FIM

Comment: I'm not sure, but if your intention was to strip ALL the tags, maybe this on is the best option: (<.*?>); 
Wich still do not resolve my problame realy, and it's because their are also texts between the tags that does'n metter and I should remove it too, like the "entre-tags-não-importam"[pt]. That's the trick one! 

Any way, thanks, and If something cames up, just say it. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: Also, did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I'll learn how to use stackoverflow formatting style, some time. But for now: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lxtDvHUmnMlZJq0vars4U72QyrYjBtE68YDWaHioiiU/edit?usp=sharing